# Cosine Rule finding the angle C

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I have the following question:

> Find $\measuredangle C$ (in radians) and the area of the triangle if $a = 5, b =4$  and $c = 8.$

What i did is find angle $C$ and once i have $C$ the rest should be easy.

\begin{align*}
c^2 &= a^2 +b^2 -2ab\,\cos(\measuredangle C)\\
64 &= 25+16-40\,\cos(\measuredangle C)\\
64 &=41-40\,\cos(\measuredangle C)\\
64-41&=-40\,\cos(\measuredangle C)\\
-40\,\cos(\measuredangle C)&=23\\
\cos(\measuredangle C)&=\frac{23}{-40}\\
\measuredangle C&=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{23}{-40}\right)
\end{align*}
but my answer is not correct the book says it should be $2.18$ rad.

Comment: $\cos^{-1}(\frac{23}{-40})$ is equal to $2.18$ radians. Check your calculator to see if it is in degree mode or radian mode.

Comment: ohhhhh my bad !